# How to update velocity when changing direction in Box2D?

Tags: box2d, physics-engine

I am writing a sprite with a body that moves at constant speed. So it goes like this in the time step:

```
const v = body.getLinearVelocity();
v.normalize();

body.setLinearVelocity(v * speed);
```

Then I want to listen to mouseclicked event and the sprite will move to the new direction accordingly.

This is what I am doing in the mouseclicked event handler:

```
const point = /* new Point on screen */
const rotation = Math.atan2(point.y - player.y, point.x - player.x);
body.setTransform(body.getPosition(), rotation);
```

But when I click the mouse my sprite will not turn to the new direction, it goes to the old direction at the same constant speed. I can see the body's angle is changed at every time step. It just won't go to the new direction.

How can I turn my sprite and move it towards a new direction in Box2D?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `applyForce()` and/or `applyImpulse()`, because that makes the body actually move. `setTransform()`, well, will "beam" it to the new transform, without any movement.

B2D will calculate all the velocities, including angular ones, when you use those `apply*` methods, what results in realistic simulation. Things like `setTransform` or `setLinearVelocity` should be used if non realistic things should occur.

If your body should behave like a real one in terms of colision and forth, you need to calculate the force needed to  to make it move to the desired new place, regularly

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand what you mean by "beam" it to the new transform. I understand that when I want it to move gradually to a speed it is better to use `applyForce()` /`applyImpulse()` but I just want it to move at constant speed, at the beginning and forever and no stop or start. My problem is how to move to a new direction while keeping its original speed.

Comment: Perhaps instead of saying "beam", we should say "teleport". `body.setTransform` just like picks up the body and places it in the new location.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity can be **instantaneously** updated by calling the `b2Body::SetLinearVelocity` method. This can potentially change the magnitude and/or the direction of a body's velocity.

To change only the direction of travel of a body:

1. Get the current linear velocity of the body (call `b2Body::GetLinearVelocity`).
2. Rotate a local copy of the returned `b2Vec2` to the new heading.
3. Set the new linear velocity to the rotated `b2Vec2` (call `b2Body::SetLinearVelocity`).

Note however that in the physical world [things with mass basically can't instantaneously change their velocities](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-instantaneously-change-velocity). So changing the velocity of your sprite this way is less realistic from a physics perspective if your sprite will have mass. If it will have mass, then as phillip explained, `applyForce` or `applyImpulse` are methods that are meant to be called to provide changes to the velocity that are more realistic (from a physics perspective).